# Structure Navigation - Not returning sub nav entries

Tags: entries, navigation, structure

I'm trying to set up a sub nav from a Structure Section on my site.

Current code is:

```
{% set mainEntry = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(1)).first() %}
{% set subnav = craft.entries.descendantOf(mainEntry).level(2) %}

{{ subnav.total() }}
```

But my when loop through sub nav below it returns nothing.
I am outputting subnav.total above but it is returning 0, but there is a lot of entries  in the CMS.

mainEntry gets loaded with the correct info ok, but I don't get anything in subnav.

Comment: Your code look right to me, mmc. What happens if you remove `.level(2)`? Are you not getting descendants at all?

Comment: No I'm getting nothing at all - when I remove .level(2) {{ subnav.total() }} still output's 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a chance that you're getting the another entry with the the same slug as your `mainEntry`? I'd try to further filter it down by adding [`section()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#section) for example.

As I wrote in the comments, try to loosen the second ElementCriteriaModel by removing the [`level`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#level) parameter.

Another idea would be to use the [`dump()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function on your `mainEntry` (only works with dev-mode turned on).

Comment: Cheers - adding section() resolved the issue - must have been another slug affecting it.